# Toy for Joy Christmas Math question.

Tags: sequences-and-series

At 11:00am, there is one (1) toy in Santa's factory. It multiplies by two (2) every  minute. At 12:00NN, the factory is already full of toys. What time was the factory half-full?

Comment: Home work question ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Nope its not a homework question. Just a trivia game. My guess is 11:30am when the factory is half full.

Comment: No ! At 11:59, I bet !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: to get from *half-full* to *full* you need a single doubling.

Comment: Also, Santa has quite a factory. Where all these $2^{59} \approx 10^{18}$ toys go to?

Comment: well i hope those toys goes to all the kids in the orphanage. :-) I don't understand the single doubling..

Comment: Thats hypothetical and magical!

Comment: @Packet This is exponential (or geometric) growth. The number doubles every minute. Since the number doubles when going from half-full to full, that takes a minute. Can you complete the puzzle now?

Answer (score 0):

If it multiplies  2  every minute so obviously it was already half full at $11:59$ am . If its $12$ noon ie $1$ min less than time when the factory is full.